# Google maps app shown in recent apps when starting as child of another one

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent

I've got the following problem:

When I'm starting a Maps-activity in my app like this

```
public void gotoNav (View view) {
    Intent nav = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=47.******,8.*****"));
    startActivity(nav);
}
```

Google Maps starts, but appears in the `recent apps`-dialog. Normally it shouldn't. And when leaving Maps via the back button (btw is there a char you can use in strings describing this button?), an "app-crashed-force-close" message appears. When I'm starting my mail app in the same way (except the URI string is `mailto:user@example.com`), neither it appears in the recent apps nor there is such a message.

What's the problem?

EDIT: The error log...

```
02-13 23:15:37.250: D/AndroidRuntime(6947): Shutting down VM
02-13 23:15:37.250: W/dalvikvm(6947): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@405bfb00 is not valid; is your activity running?
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:532)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:200)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:114)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.view.android.aL.show(SourceFile:52)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.view.android.S.s(SourceFile:758)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.android.BaseMapsActivity.actuallyShow(SourceFile:102)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.android.BaseMapsActivity.showDialog(SourceFile:88)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.view.android.S.l(SourceFile:404)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.view.android.S.show(SourceFile:390)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.ca.c(SourceFile:372)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.ca.b(SourceFile:404)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.C.j(SourceFile:194)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.ca.a(SourceFile:661)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.ca.b(SourceFile:401)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.C.j(SourceFile:194)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.ca.a(SourceFile:246)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.ca.a(SourceFile:261)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.ca.a(SourceFile:205)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.jv.c(SourceFile:352)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.wizard.jv.e(SourceFile:1597)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.s.c(SourceFile:5496)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.A.f(SourceFile:448)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.A.a(SourceFile:387)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.ui.s.a(SourceFile:5336)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.android.M.a(SourceFile:2356)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.android.M.o(SourceFile:1730)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.android.M.k(SourceFile:1043)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.android.M.a(SourceFile:720)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity.processIntentAndStartSession(SourceFile:1031)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.android.maps.w.a(SourceFile:836)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.google.googlenav.x.run(SourceFile:127)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-13 23:15:37.281: E/AndroidRuntime(6947):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 23:15:37.289: E/liblog(1495): failed to call dumpstate
02-13 23:15:37.296: E/(1495): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: Post the log of the crash you are getting.

Comment: When you tell me the filter criteria to show Maps logs only (Something with app:...)

Comment: If something is crashing the logcat message will be red. Just monitor logcat in eclipse, perform your action to make the app crash, notice the red text in logcat with the error. Copy that, paste here..

Comment: i've added it in the question.